# how to capture screen when user click on link - chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome

I am novice to chrome extensions 
When a user clicks on the link in my extension,

1)  I  want capture the selected tab screen  and

2)   Open up a new email with the captured screen shot as attachment

i have tried by calling "show1()" function to capture the screen when user clicks on the link but no result/no alert

```
function show1(){
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null,{"format":"png"}, function(imgUrl) {
        alert(imgUrl);                                            
    });    
  }
```

Thanks in advance , 
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `"format"` to just `format`.

Still, I think you'll run into problems generating a `mailto:` link because you'd be including the img data, which is a *very* long string. But you might be able to display the image at least somewhere with `'<img src="'+imgUrl+'" />'` and have the user Right-click > Save the image so that they can attach it to an email later.

However, this wouldn't be able to be done within a Page Action, nor a Browser Action, because you can't right-click on those. But you could execute a content script to the selected tab and have the image be displayed on the existing page for the user to save.

Comment: i am getting the undefined error/msg in alert box, 
could any one help me whats wrongs with call ?